# Selecting one cell once, but everything else

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
      groups                  group_members
    v-------------------------------v
 +----+------------+     +----+----------+------+
 | id | group_name |     | id | group_id | name |
 +----+------------+     +----+----------+------+
 | 1  | admin      |     | 1  | 1        | Dave |
 +----+------------+     +----+----------+------+
 | 2  | moderator  |     | 2  | 1        | Bob  |
 +----+------------+     +----+----------+------+
 | 3  | vip        |     | 3  | 2        | Sue  |
 +----+------------+     +----+----------+------+
 | 4  | user       |     | 4  | 2        | Jill |
 +----+------------+     +----+----------+------+
                         | 5  | 2        | Jack |
                         +----+----------+------+
                         | 6  | 3        | Bill |
                         +----+----------+------+
                         | 7  | 4        | Sam  |
                         +----+----------+------+
```

`group_members` has a foreign key reference from `group_id` to `id` in `groups`.

I want to obtain the roster of members found in a group, but also return the `group_name` in the process. I would like to do this in one query only.

I've tried this query but it returns the group name for every row, I'd like to see the `group_name` as its own row.

```
SELECT groups.group_name, 
       group_members.name 
FROM   groups, 
       group_members 
WHERE  group_members.group_id = groups.id 
       AND groups.id = 1
```

The result is:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
| groups.group_name | group_members.name |
+-------------------+--------------------+
| admin             | Dave               |
+-------------------+--------------------+
| admin             | Bob                |
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I'd like to see:

```
  either this |                     or this |
              v                             v
+-------------------+            +---------------------+
| groups.group_name |            | groups_members.name |
+-------------------+            +---------------------+
| admin             |            | admin               |
+-------------------+            +---------------------+
                                 | Dave                |
+---------------------+          +---------------------+
| groups_members.name |          | Bob                 |
+---------------------+          +---------------------+
| Dave                |
+---------------------+
| Bob                 |
+---------------------+
```

Would that be possible?

Comment: this can be done using Union , i m not sure how to do in single query

Comment: why? You are mangling the data by removing the column-names... what is the problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps there's a better way of solving it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT if(gm.name='',g.name,gm.name) as name
FROM   groups g
       join (select group_id, name from group_members gm
                  union all
                  select 1 as group_id, '' as name) gm on
       gm.group_id = g.id 
WHERE
       groups.id = 1
```

We can add one more artificial row and choose either group name (for the additional row) or group member name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT groups.group_name      
FROM   groups, 
       group_members 
WHERE  group_members.group_id = groups.id 
       AND groups.id = 1 

UNION

SELECT group_members.name 
FROM   groups, 
       group_members 
WHERE  group_members.group_id = groups.id 
       AND groups.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This one?

```
SELECT groups.group_name AS Name
FROM   groups JOIN group_members ON
               group_members.group_id = groups.id 
WHERE groups.id = 1 
UNION
SELECT group_members.name AS Name
FROM   group_members JOIN groups ON
               group_members.group_id = groups.id 
WHERE groups.id = 1
```